# What kind of Lego-compatible figures are these?

Tags: part-identification, minifigures, clone-brands

Can anyone tell me about these Lego-compatible figures? They clearly aren't Lego brand, they don't look like Mega Blok figures or Tyco figures that I have seen (not that they couldn't be one of those brands potentially). They have no brand markings on them anywhere that I've found, but they can attach to standard Lego bricks. (bonus: how valuable are they? not very?) edit: some of the football characters (but not the coaches/plain people) have levers on their back and one locking leg.
[image: figures]

Comment: I have some of that. It's a asian brand that consists of blocks with not studs, but rods.

Comment: did you ever find any more out about these? I have been given a box load of bricks, plates and figures that look just like yours!! [More minifigures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ebl29.jpg)

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer! They are early Best-Lock, before Best-Lock merged with Cobi and was still manufactured in Colne, UK. In fact, here is the set that gave it away! [image][image]

Answer (score 4):

My first guess is that these are early generation Oyo Sportstoys (http://www.oyosports.com). The legs on the current version of Oyo figures are different (they have an articulated foot) but perhaps there was an earlier iteration of them that looks like the ones you have?

Answer (score 4):

I've seen things like this called "soldier bear". they're made of really light grade plastic and their hats plug into heads inversely to legos.

[image]

Comment: Your photo looks like a perfect match as to the type of figure, but I've never heard of Soldier Bear before and was unsuccessful in finding any information or pictures using soldier bear as one of my search keywords. Do you have any additional information about the brand, packaging, etc?

Comment: Uh.. no. My bro keeps it in a second-hand box. If it helps, the set contains 3 (maybe originally 4) soldiers, a tank, a palm tree, and a small fortress. No pieces bear (hehe, bad pun) a brand name.