# Identify these vintage-looking clone-brand minifigs

Tags: clone-brands, minifigure-identification, vintage

I have been given them with a lot of blocks from years back. The blocks have higher plates than Lego, and the underneath looks like Loc Blocs / Brix Blox / Kawada… but searching these brands doesn’t reveal any of these happy little people. They definitely have a vintage feel about them. Can anyone advise?

[image: Vintage Block People]

These minifigs seem to be similar to the ones in [this other (unanswered) question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/5961/what-kind-of-lego-compatible-figures-are-these).

Comment: Not sure if these can be called vintage. This is just how generic Chinese clone-brand figures look like.

Comment: Hi Christopher and welcome to Bricks.SE! Please take a look at the [tour] and the [help] pages to learn more about how this site operates, what can you expect and what is expected of you in return. Have a nice day - don't forget to respond to comments and rate and mark any helpful answers. Have a nice stay!

Comment: The plastic is much softer than the usual ABS… I think it’s more like the stuff the Lego plants and trees are made from…

Comment: And the linked "unanswered" question has answers, just none that have been accepted as THE answer.  The answers there actually seem to cover most of what you're asking about.